# TCPDF - addEmptySignatureAppearance into table cell

Tags: php, tcpdf

I use TCPDF to sign pdf files with a certificate. In addition to signing files, I make it possible for other users to sign the file by adding an empty field to the signature: `$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(100, 120, 100, 15);`
In the above call, you need to specify the coordinates of the field to be signed. Is it possible to have such a field in a table cell?
e.g.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Signature</th></tr>
<tr><td>----SIGNATURE HERE----</td></tr>
</table>
```

Each document has a different structure and the table will be in a different place, so providing constant coordinates is not necessary